# Binary Search the hightes value for which a function is false in R

Tags: r, binary-search

I have an expensiv function that can be called with an positive integer. Starting at zero this function returns false, at a certain value (call this value y) the function will return true and will return also true for all inputvalues higher than y.

What i tried: I defined a function (in reality this function takes a very long time to execute)

```
magicFun <- function(x) x > 10
```

detect (Package `purrr`) does work, but is too slow for my use case (remember in my case magicFun takes a lot of time)

```
> detect(0:100,magicFun)
[1] 11
```

binsearch (Package `gtools`) does not work, as it will return the first value that returns false (but I want the **highest** value)

```
binsearch(magicFun, range = c(0,100), showiter = T)
```

Comment: You have a sequence of all `FALSE` up to a point and then all `TRUE`? In R logical values are coded as `0/1` so `which.max` might be what you want, it returns the first maximum. `which.max(magicFun(0:100))` returns 12 (the first `TRUE`) so the last `FALSE` is 11.

Comment: And `which.max` is orders of magnitude faster than `purrr::detect`.

Comment: If there is any chance that you post the function or a boiled-down version of it. As stated below as well, I can hardly imagine a function that takes 10 times longer if the input vector is 10 times longer. If this is really the case, then chances are the function itself can be strongly improved.

Comment: @Georgery The function, this might be a bit weird, is a HTTP GET call which might take up to a second. The server is not under my controll. So yes 10 times more calls will take 10 times longer. So in short, improving the function is unfortunately not a option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
binsearch(magicFun, range = c(0,100), showiter = T, target = 0.5)
```

This tells the search algorithm to look for 0.5, which is in the middle of `TRUE` and `FALSE`.  It will return the largest `FALSE` and the smallest `TRUE`.

If this is still too slow, then you'll have to optimize the expensive function.

Comment: This is brilliant! And a strange solution! But it does exactly what i want!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write this yourself, because you have unusual needs, i.e. you *do not* want to pass a vector to `magicFun`, you only want to pass scalars, you want to pass as few as possible of those, and you don't have a typical stopping rule:  you need to stop at `n` where `magicFun(n)` is `TRUE` but `magicFun(n-1)` is `FALSE`.

Do you have any idea about how big the answer will be in advance?  If for example you think it will be around 100, you could start a binary search at 0 and 120.  You will need to be prepared for your initial guess to be wrong, i.e. maybe 120 gives `FALSE`.

I'll let you write the function yourself.

Comment: This answer sounds weird to me. Passing scalars? But there are no scalars in R. Everything is a vector. What kind of a function is it that performs that much different on a vector of length 1 than on a vector of length 100?

Comment: @Georgery:  the accepted solution only passes scalars, i.e. length 1 vectors, to `magicFun`.  If the answer is known to be no more than 100 (as in the sample code) it's perfect.  If the upper limit is not known, then it would need some elaboration.